# Проблема чтения файла

Tags: java, android, input, потоки-данных, fileoutputstream

Проблема такая, есть файл, нужно из файла (состоит из `html` тэгов и картинок `base64`) записать в строку содержимое.
Использовал `FileReader`, `InputStreamReader` и т.д.
Интересно вот что, обычный текст (не `html`) читает, и выводит все, а вот с чтением `html` страницы проблема. Кодировку менять пробовал при чтении файла.
Думал вначале, что объем файла большой (программа виснет и начинает память выделять).

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `а вот с чтением ... проблема` какая конкретно проблема? Пример своего кода можете привести?

Comment: Проблему со чтением решил, теперь проблема больших объемов, все в строку не засунуть.

Answer (score 0):

Класс `InputStreamReader` является мостом для текстовых, а не бинарных стримов, точнее он преобразует стрим в текст, и если там действительно только текст, то он читается. В противном случае результат невозможно предсказать.